# React native flatlist multiple selection is not updating

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using a flatlist to expose all the list of ingredients I have saved on my database, but once I update the state, it is not reflecting on the flatlist component.

The flatlist component

```
<FlatList
  horizontal
  bounces={false}
  key={ingredientList.id}
  data={ingredientList}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => selectedIngredient(item)}>
      <Card key={item.id}>
        <Text key={item.title} style={styles.titleText}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text key={item.title} style={styles.titleText}>{item.isSelected?'selected':'not selected'} 
        </Text>
        <ImageBackground key={item.illustration} source={item.illustration} style={styles.cardImage}> 
        </ImageBackground>
      </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.index}
/>
```

This is the function that find the selected item "selectedIngredient"

```
function selectedIngredient(item) {
    console.log('received: ', item.name)
    item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
    return { ...item.isSelected }
}
```

That component call is working when I try debbug with console.log after the "item.isSelected = !item.isSelected", but the IU is not updated. Can someone help me to understand how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set state by using either `setState` in a class-based component or either using `useState` hook in the functional component.

```
function selectedIngredient(item) {
    console.log('received: ', item.name)
    item.isSelected = !item.isSelected; //this is not how you set state
    return { ...item.isSelected }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: snapshot]

here is our old example which I modified for your current scenario:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm

const ingredientList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'item1',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'item 2',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'item 3',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'item 4',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'item 5',
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'item 6',
    selected: false,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState(ingredientList);

  const selectedIngredient = (item) => {
    console.log('selecionado: ' + item.name);
    setSelectedItem(item);
    /* Below operation can be improved by passing index to the function itself.
       so filtering would not be required
     */
    let temp = allItems.filter((parentItem) => parentItem.id !== item.id);
    item.selected = !item.selected;
    temp = temp.concat(item);
    temp.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id));
    setAllItems(temp);
    console.log(allItems);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flatlist}
        horizontal
        bounces={false}
        data={allItems}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.flatListItem}
            key={item.id}
            onPress={() => selectedIngredient(item)}>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            {!item.selected ? (
              <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{'Not Selected'}</Text>
            ) : (
              <Text style={{ color: 'green' }}>{'Selected'}</Text>
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.index}
      />

      {selectedItem ? (
        <View style={styles.selectedTextView}>
          <Text style={styles.selectedText}>{`${selectedItem.name} ${
            selectedItem.selected ? 'selected' : 'not selected'
          }`}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.selectedTextView}>
          <Text style={styles.selectedText}>{`Nothing selected`}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  flatListItem: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  selectedTextView: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  selectedText: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});
```

[Live Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/flatlist_example)

Comment: Your example is exacly what I need, but when I updated my code with this structure the "ingredientList" is not updateding the "allItems" state
when the component is mounted it is showing only the initial state.
The selected value is working, but not over the dataset. Do you know why it is happening?
When I use the console.log to see the "ingredientList", it has the respective value.

Comment: can I get the data i.e. ```ingredientList``` on which you are trying to perform state modification?
And about why your code is behaving the way it is, I have to take a look at the whole concerned code...
Try looking at the above example and try on your own for a while :)
It's a relatively simple task and you can implement it once you understand the above example.

Comment: I will try to implement like you did and refactoring the component. Thank you very much!